# geom_signif between boxplots of different x and same group

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, boxplot

How could I test differences between boxplots x='a' and x='b', both being group='g1', and then between boxplots x='a' and x='b' both being group='g2'?

```
d = data.frame(c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','b'),
               c(13, 12, 12, 5, 14, 6, 10, 11),
               c('g1','g2','g1','g2','g1','g2','g1','g2')) %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("x", "y", "group"))

> d
  x  y group
1 a 13    g1
2 a 12    g2
3 a 12    g1
4 a  5    g2
5 b 14    g1
6 b  6    g2
7 b 10    g1
8 b 11    g2

ggplot(d,
       aes(x, y,
           fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = combn(levels(factor(d$x)), 2, simplify = F))
```

This shows the result of testing "a" vs. "b":

[image]

but what I would like to obtain is that stratified by group, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use an interaction between the `x` and `group` variables:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggsignif)

d %>%
  mutate(x2 = interaction(group, x)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x2, y, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c(1, 3),
                                 c(2, 4)), 
              y_position = rep(max(d$y), 2) * c(1, 1.05))
```

[image]

This changes the labelling on the x axis which may not be desired.  To keep the axis the same as your original plot we can mimic a discrete scale by using a continuous one and setting the breaks and labels appropriately.

```
d %>%
  mutate(x2 = as.integer(interaction(group, x))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x2, y, group = x2, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c(1, 3),
                            c(2, 4)),
              y_position = rep(max(d$y), 2) * c(1, 1.05)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1.5, 3.5), labels = c("a", "b"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have to wait to give you the bounty 22h though